# Hiding div based on cookie value when loading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have created a div and used jquery to hide and show the div. When the user click on hide I want to hide the div for 5 minutes till the user loads the page again. I have saved the state (whether hidden or not) in a cookie. When the user is loading the page for the second time within 5 mins the div should be hidden. I have tried the code below and it is not working. Can somebody help me with this?

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (getCookie(hidden) === "yes") {
                $("#divAlert").hide();
                if ($("#Hide").is(":visible")) {
                    $("#Hide").css("visibility", "hidden");
                }

                $("#Show").css("visibility", "visible");
            }


            $("#Hide").click(function () {
                $("#divAlert").hide();
                if ($("#Hide").is(":visible")) {
                    $("#Hide").css("visibility", "hidden");
                }
                setCookie();
                $("#Show").css("visibility", "visible");

            });

            $("#Show").click(function () {
                $("#divAlert").show();

                $("#Hide").css("visibility", "visible");


                if ($("#Show").is(":visible")) {
                    $("#Show").css("visibility", "hidden");
                }
            });           
        });

        function setCookie() {
            var currentDate = new Date();
            document.cookie = "hidden=yes;exppires=" + currentDate.getMinutes() + 1;
        }

        function getCookie(cookiename) {
            var results = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + cookie_name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');

            if (results)
                return (unescape(results[2]));
            else
                return null;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Have read this **http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `getCookie()` and `setCookie()` functions work properly, this line of your code:

```
getCookie(hidden);
```

should be:

```
getCookie("hidden");
```

You would have seen this problem immediately if you looked at your javascript error console as this is probably a script error.

The rest of your code can be simplified like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (getCookie(hidden) === "yes") {
            $("#divAlert").hide();
            $("#Hide").css("visibility", "hidden");
            $("#Show").css("visibility", "visible");
        }


        $("#Hide").click(function () {
            $("#divAlert").hide();
            $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
            $("#Show").css("visibility", "visible");
            setCookie();

        });

        $("#Show").click(function () {
            $("#divAlert").show();
            $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
            $("#Hide").css("visibility", "visible");
        });           
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `getCookie(cookiename)` function, it references `cookie_name` which should be `cookiename`.