# Show a div in asp.net on condition

Tags: asp.net, cookies

Is it Possible to show/notshow a div in asp.net depending if cookies are set or not?
Note: the div is an html form invoked with javascript in asp.net.

Here the code in asp.net

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="Server">   
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () { $('#'<%= webform.ClientID %>).load('popup.html'); 
</script><div id="webform" runat="Server">
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

And in code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ webform.Visible= true;}
```

Note that the webform is visible when the code is: (nothing is code behind)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () { $('#webform').load('popup.html'); })
 </script>
 <div id="webform" >
 </div>
 </asp:Content>
```

The goal is to make this visible or not depending if cookie has been set or not.
I already tested that the form (in HTML) is setting the cookies(with javascript through webform)

Comment: Yes it is possible..but first you need to show us what have u tried so far.

Comment: I have a asp.net website. I designed a form(popup) in html which set the cookies on the client browser. I use javascript from asp.net to call the pop up and everything is fine. I want now show or not this form based on condition if cookies are set or not. I don't know if to make the div run at server and write a function in the code behind that read cookies first and then show or not the pop up. Or can I do this directly with javascript without using code behind?

Comment: If I make the "div" containing the webform "runa t server" the pop up is no longer displayed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227160/hiding-div-based-on-cookie-value-when-loading-the-page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741612/show-hide-div-using-codebehind   reading this

Comment: Once you make your DIV a server control by adding runat="server" the id of it will be changed in server side. That's why your JavaScript code can't find it. But, if you make use of DIV's ClientID value you could still do it

Comment: Don't add answers your self unless you found the solution yourself. Rather update your question with the code you tried. See my updated answers to get an idea how you'd use DIV server control in JQuery

Comment: And, ff you don't add a comment here we won't get notified

Comment: can you edit your question and paste your markup code and code behind code.

Comment: Check my update 2. Vote and answer if it works. All the best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the logic for you to try

1. Make your DIV a server control by adding `runat="server"` property
2. Also have an `ID` property for your DIV tag
3. set this DIV's visibility from your code behind based on the Cookie values

E.g.

Markup code

```
<div id="MyDiv" runat="server"></div>
```

Code behind

```
MyDiv.Visible = true; // set this based on the cookie value
```

**UPDATE 1**

This is how you'd use your DIV in Scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () { $('#'<%= MyDiv.ClientID %>).load('popup.html'); })
</script>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I made a mistake in my UPDATE 1. You should write the JQuery selector like `'#<%= MyDiv.ClientID %>'` and not like `'#'<%= MyDiv.ClientID %>` (Note the ' marks).

And, you also made a mistake in your script. You've missed a **})** at the end of the script.

Anyway, here's the working solution. (I tried it so don't tell it's not working :-))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () { $('#<%= webform.ClientID %>').load('popup.html');} )
</script>
<div id="webform" runat="Server"></div>
```

Hope you could understand this.

Comment: `<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="Server">
   
   
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () { $('#webform').load('popup.html'); })
    </script>
  
     <div id="webform"  >
    </div>

</asp:Content>`

Comment: `$('#'<%= MyDiv.ClientID %>).`  - not clear what is the ClientID. thanks for the tips about how to properly post  comments.

Comment: `<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="Server">
   
   
     <script type="text/javascript">
         
         $(document).ready(function () { $('#'<%= webform.ClientID %>).load('popup.html'); 
         
    </script>
  
     <div id="webform" runat="Server" >
    </div>

</asp:Content>`

Comment: but still cannot get it visible

Comment: ClientID is the ID generated by the server, which is rendered to the client. This value is only available for server controls. I.e. if you use runat="server"

Comment: Thank you I google the use of ClientID and I understand the theory. No error. Just the pop up cannot be displayed if I put "run at server" and visible in the code behid (suppose that I am doing it right after the Page_Load method)

Comment: Ok, can you edit your question and paste your markup code and code behind code.

Comment: Suppose that I added to the DIV the "run at server", and I modified the script with "'#'<%= webform.ClientID %>).", and I placed in code behind MyDiv.Visible = true; Is this structure correct???  `   <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="Server">
   
     <script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function () { $('#webform').load('popup.html'); })

    </script>

    <div id="webform" >
    </div>
   
</asp:Content>  `

Comment: don't know twhy but to vote up requires to have 15 reputation

Comment: There should be an option (tick or chekbox) next to my answer to accept it as an answer. And, use up and down arrows next to my answer to vote up or vote down.

Comment: Vote up requires 15 reputation so i cannot do it but i accepted the answer :-) thank you

Comment: No worries. That's how you say thank you in SO :-) Happy coding!